# Extract value from xml element tag

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have the following xquery expression for returning the title of a particular CD from an XML databases

```
String queryString =
                "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;"  + sep +    
                "for $cd in doc($docName)/*/"+"CD[1]"+"/TITLE"+        
                " return $cd/text()";
     XQPreparedExpression expr = conn.prepareExpression(queryString);
     expr.bindString(new QName("docName"), filename,
              conn.createAtomicType(XQItemType.XQBASETYPE_STRING));
     XQResultSequence rs = expr.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
         System.out.println(rs.getObject());
     }
```

The output I get from this query has the following format

```
[#text: 1999 Grammy Nominees]
```

The question is that, how can improve the query to make the output get rid of that "#text:" thing, and produce only -1999 Grammy Nominees-.
Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: What XML database is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
String queryString =
                "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;"  + sep +    
                "for $cd in doc($docName)/*/"+"CD[1]"+"/TITLE"+        
                " return string($cd)";

XQResultSequence rs = expr.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
         System.out.println(rs.getAtomicValue());
     }
```

do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does, Thank you much Martin

Comment: You arr right, Dimitre, it needs to be `getAtomicValue`. It seems my typing deteriorates, I am too much used to an editor with Intellisense that autocompletes method or property names. I will edit and fix the code.